# Shared user for an application or hard link of settings on every user's home?

Tags: permissions

I have some experience on Linux but on permissions I have very little experience.

I have some solutions to my problems, but I want to know which solution is the best.

Problem: DOSBox shared for all users.

Solution 1: Games and settings hardlinked from my home directory to everyone's home directory.

Solution 2: DOSBox run with specific user, shared for all users (I am not totally sure how to do this, but I am almost sure that it is easy) and all games and settings are in that user's home directory. Let say the user is "shared_user".

Problem: Wine needs a lot to support beautiful greek fonts. I must download greek fonts for each user. Also for many programs need to configure windows registry, stored per user.

Solution 1: as previous.

Solution 2: as previous. In that case, If I have a private .EXE program, not accecible from other users, can I run it with "shared_user"?

Which of 2 solutions is better?

Answer (score 1):

When you need all users to have certain privileges to a directory or a file you can make use of SUID or SGID. You can read on these here [What is SUID, SGID and Sticky bit ?](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/what-is-suid-sgid-and-sticky-bit/).

Basically, the file with the SUID set will always be executed as if the file owner executed it. This would be the most similar to your solution number 2.